# update query join table

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join

I want update status column where id table 1 = id table 2 and status = ''

```
table1
===========================
id | delivery_status | name
===========================

table2 
=============
id | status | 
=============
```

delivery status on table1 and status on table2 are different case.

I just have one row match (id table 1 = id table 2) and 2 rows no match. if I query:

```
UPDATE myschema.table1
SET status = 'COMPLETED'
FROM myschema.table1 t1, myschema.table2 t2
WHERE t2.delivery_status = 'B' and t1.status = '' and t1.id = t2.id;
```

If this select, the result have 1 row, but when I execute this update query, 3 rows are update to `COMPLETED`. how to fix this problem? I just want to update one row. I already add the condition `t1.id = t2.id`. The id on table 1 and table 2 just match one row.

Answer (score 1):

Only include the table to update once

```
UPDATE myschema.table1
SET status = 'COMPLETED'
FROM myschema.table2 t2
WHERE t2.delivery_status = 'B' and table1.status = '' and table1.id = t2.id;
```